# Spring Kafka Custom Deserializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, json-deserialization

I am following the steps listed in this [link](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-kafka) to create a customer deserializer. The message that I receive from Kafka has plain text "log message -" before the json string.I want the deserializer to ignore this string and parse the json data. Is there a way to do it?

**Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TransactionauditServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(TransactionauditServiceApplication.class).web(false).run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageListener messageListener() {
        return new MessageListener();
    }

    public static class MessageListener {

        @KafkaListener(topics = "ctp_verbose", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
        public void listen(@Payload ConciseMessage message, 
                  @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition) {
            System.out.println("Received Messasge in group foo: " + message.getStringValue("traceId") + " partion " + partition);
        }
    }
}
```

**ConsumerConfig**

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress:localhost:9092}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Value(value = "${groupId:audit}")
    private String groupId;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, ConciseMessage> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(ConciseMessage.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ConciseMessage> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ConciseMessage> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't your deserializer simply omit this text bit and parse the JSON after it?

Comment: I have pasted the code. It is implicitly being done. I would like to intercept and omit the text bit.

Comment: `new JsonDeserializer<>(ConciseMessage.class)` - that is not a custom one is it?

Comment: This is the custom message. The json data is of type ConciseMessage

Comment: No I meant, that the deserializer class is not something you have come up with, is it?

Comment: No , I use ConciseMessage class to deserialize. I don't have to come up with something. Sorry , if I still didn't answer your question

Comment: By writing the line `new JsonDeserializer<>(ConciseMessage.class)`, you are just telling Kafka that you want to convert the message to a `ConciseMessage` type. So, that doesn't make it a custom deserializer. To fix your problem you will most likely have to come up with your own implementation of a deserializer that has the logic to strip the text "log message -"

Comment: Thank you! Is there an example that I can follow?

Comment: I believe I can use this - http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization. Thank you very much!

Comment: Absolutely, you have it there :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing the line `new JsonDeserializer<>(ConciseMessage.class)`, you are just telling Kafka that you want to convert the message to a `ConciseMessage` type. So, that doesn't make it a custom deserializer. To fix your problem you will most likely have to come up with your own implementation of a deserializer that has the logic to strip the text "log message -".